# Change values for duplicates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

The dataframe given is

```
var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
  23     1     0     0     0
  23     0     0     0     1
  43     0     0     0     1
  43     0     1     1     0
```

I need to check values of variables var2, var3, var4, var5 and change binary values that for the rows with duplicates in var1, all other variables have the same values. When deciding which duplicate is to be changed, the priority is given to var2.
So I need to have my final dataframe as follows:

```
var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
  23     1     0     0     0
  23     1     0     0     0
  43     0     1     1     1
  43     0     1     1     1
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: What are the parameters for how `var2` is changed? Is it the first occurrence? Is it the max value?

Comment: Why is 1 in var5 replaced (row 2)?

Comment: Chris, if one of duplicates has value of var2=1, another duplicates has to be adjusted accordingly. When var2=1, var3=, var4=, var 5 =0.

Comment: When var2!=1, all others =1 and must be the same for all duplicates

Comment: anky_91, because the second row which is the duplicate of the first one (by var1), and must be adjusted due to given prioryty to var2

Comment: then why is 0s replaced by 1  in row 3?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not well explained since my answer got 2 downgrades:) I hope you will forgive me for that as this is my first code to facilitate implementation of a set of rules that I have been applying in excel but want to automotize the process.
I will explain in other words. 
Basically, I have a list of tranacitons and var1 is a transactional ID. Variables are decisions that I'm taking regarding each transaction. var2 - reject, var3 - correct; var4 - accept; var5 - accept and "do something else". The same transactions must have the same decision taken. Happened that for some transactions, decision are taken separately, reason why they have different decisions. My goal is to adjust decisions for the same transactions in the same way. 
Regarding decisions, reject (var2) has a priority.If one is rejected, another must be also rejected. A priority of var2 comes from here. 
If var1=1; others=0
Regarding other variables. They may have ones not exeptionally, eg. var3= 1; var4=1; var5=1; but in this case var2=0 (always). Important that transactions with the same ID have the same decisions.
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood your logic:

```
import pandas as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [23, 23, 43, 43],
                   'var2': [1, 0, 0, 0],
                   'var3': [0, 0, 0, 1],
                   'var4': [0, 0, 0, 1],
                   'var5': [0, 1, 1, 0]})
print(df)
df['var2'] = df.groupby(['var1'])['var2'].transform('max')
f = 1 - df['var2']
df['var3'], df['var4'],df['var5'] =[f]*3

print(df)
```

output:

```
var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
  23     1     0     0     0
  23     1     0     0     0
  43     0     1     1     1
  43     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you. Frenchy. I like the solution for the comparing and  transforming var2. After doing the first operation df['var2'] = df.groupby(['var1'])['var2'].transform('max'). I just need to eliminate ones for other variables, implementing somethin like "if var2=1", var3,4,5=0.

Comment: To treat other variables i will probably need more general rule

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it. Maybe it's too long but it works :)
Thank you Frenchy once again for "groupby" suggestion!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [23, 23, 43, 43, 53],
                   'var2': [1, 0, 0, 0,1],
                   'var3': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   'var4': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   'var5': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})
print(df)

df['Dup'] = np.where(df['var1'].duplicated(keep=False), 'dup', np.nan)

df['var2'] = np.where(df['Dup']=="dup", df.groupby(['var1'])['var2'].transform('max'), df['var2'])
df['var3'] = np.where((df['Dup']=="dup") & (df['var2']==1), 0 , df['var3'])
df['var4'] = np.where((df['Dup']=="dup") & (df['var2']==1), 0 , df['var4'])
df['var5'] = np.where((df['Dup']=="dup") & (df['var2']==1), 0 , df['var5'])

df['others_dup'] = np.where((df['Dup']=='dup') & (df['var2']==0), 1, np.nan)

df['var3']=np.where(df['others_dup']==1, df.groupby(['var1'])['var3'].transform('max'), df['var3'])
df['var4']=np.where(df['others_dup']==1, df.groupby(['var1'])['var4'].transform('max'), df['var4'])
df['var5']=np.where(df['others_dup']==1, df.groupby(['var1'])['var5'].transform('max'), df['var5'])

print(df)
```